# If object.assign is built-in why using bable-plugin for it?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-plugin

I found this plugins in `.babelrc` file

```
"plugins": [
["transform-replace-object-assign", "object.assign"] ]
```

and as i know `Object.assign()` is built-in method in all modern browsers.

So why using it as plugins inside .babelrc?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not supported in IE

Comment: It a polyfill for older browsers that don't support it.

Comment: Reductio ad absurdum: Why use babel whatsoever?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty what do you suggest?

Comment: @JimmyJanson I was making a type of logical argument that could be a(n absurd) follow-up to your original question -- why use Babel whatsoever if various methods such as `Object.assign` are built-in?  The answer is, because Babel is specifically meant for when these methods are *not* built-in, e.g. non-modern browsers.  So keep using Babel -- but maybe look up "reductio ad absurdum": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you define "modern browsers". `Object.assign` isn't present in Internet Explorer, which accounts for about one in eight users at the time of writing.

Whatever the case, depending on the purpose of your website, you may wish to support all kinds of users using all kinds of browsers. Remember, many users are unable or unwilling to upgrade their browser for various reasons.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[Object.assign is not supported in IE.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility)

It's not about supporting modern browsers - but as many browsers as possible. That said, it's always a good idea to include babel and polyfills for older browsers so you can write in modern JS but still support the less modern browsers.

Comment: it came with price i guess, more bandle size if want to install the method as dependency

Comment: Always a trade-off. You can also just use something like lodash which takes care of polyfilling so you can use the same syntax and it'll just default back if static object methods are not supported.